# Cannot find namespace 'moment'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ionic 2.

I create new project

```
ionic start Ismart --v2
```

The project was successfully created.

I tried to run the project using ionic serve

I am getting this err

```
Cannot find namespace 'moment'
```

Here is my Package.Json

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.1.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.6",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "ISmartpremises: An Ionic project"
}
```

How can i fix this issue...

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `moment.js`?

Comment: same question.. can you share package.json?

Comment: @Sampath.I am not using anything.Just create a project and run.

Comment: @suraj.Kindly check i update my package.json

Comment: what does ionic info say? I just tried a fresh project..no issues

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any issue in your `package.json` file.I think you have forgotten to change the directory.

You can try as shown below.

```
d:\ionic2 > ionic start Ismart blank --v2

d:\ionic2\Ismart> ionic serve
```

Comment: Is this the issue? @ANISUNDAR